# Games already linked to the console?

Tags: wii-u

On the launch of the Wii-U, the console was linked directly to the Nintendo account, which means:

If you purchase a game (I think, just online) it will be saved on the console and can be re-downloaded. But if you buy another console, you have to buy it again.

Was this fixed sometime in the past? Are there now accounts like on steam, where the bought games are listed and where it is possible to have different computers with the same accounts?

Or is it like before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like before. I called Nintendo customer service a few days ago when my hard drive was having problems, and they said that is still true. The account is tied to the console. If it breaks, the best thing to do is send it to Nintendo and have them fix it, because

1. It wont cost as much as buying a new Wii U
2. They can save your data, or at least your account.

That was told to me by customer service at Nintendo, and I've had to have a console repaired by Nintendo before, and it's always gone smoothly. All my data was intact and just like it should be.

While it may take a little more time to send it in, it's cheaper than buying a new console, and you keep all your account data. In my opinion, that's the obvious choice for when a console breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bud. :)

But this is just for the games you purchase online, right? If you buy the retail ones, there's no such DRM on it? Can you play them on any Wii-U?

Comment: @TrudleR None of the next gen consoles disallow game usage in that manner.  If you have the physical disk, you can play it.

Comment: yup. what fbueckert said. You buy a disc, it'll work in any Wii U console you like. Being tied to your account is only for purchases from the eshop.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. Great thanks! :D

@fbueckert: Computer-Retailgames won't allow this if they use steam as their "DRM". The XBox-One also wanted to jump on this train first. But I'm glad that this isn't like this on the Wii-U. :)

Comment: Nope! Nintendo is very understanding as far as used games go. Their actual philosophy was "We make games so good that people dont WANT to trade them or get rid of them." I personally agree :P